# npm start command compiled with errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm

I decided to create an app with React using VS Code. Ran the `npm create-react-app ./` and was successful. Next I decided to run the command `npm start` but it compiled with errors like
`/src/index.js and  [eslint]  src\index.jsur`

Comment: You haven't provide enough information in order to determine what the problem is (at least, not for me). There are a couple of things that don't make sense, like `npm create-react-app ./` which is incorrect, you need to specify the name of the app not the location (`app-name` instead of `./`) and `src\index.jsur` seems like a file you've created (I don't think `create-react-app` will generate any files with the `.jsur` extension).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure to execute `npm start` in the project directory, inside of the same folder where is located `package.json`

I would recommend to check npm version, and use npx for the creation of the react project, `npx create-react-app myapp`. and after execute something else, check the `package.json` content.